# To generate a list, allowing duplicates and fitting a condition

Tags: python, list, random, combinations

From choices [1,2,3], I want to output all possible combinations, allowing duplicates in the choices, in a list of 5 elements.

In each of the lists, there must be at least one of 1, at least one of 2, and at least one of 3.

A clumsy way as below. It firstly generates a list of 5 using either in [1,2,3]. All generated lists are examined to have at least each of [1,2,3]. The qualified ones are put into a big list. Then the duplicates in the big list are removed (loop it many times to make sure good coverage):

```
import random
import itertools

choices = [1,2,3]

big_list = []

for a in range(10000):
    new_list = [random.choice(choices) for i in range(5)]

    if new_list.count(1) >= 1 and new_list.count(2) >= 1 and new_list.count(3) >= 1:
        big_list.append(new_list)

big_list.sort()

final_list = list(big_list for big_list, _ in itertools.groupby(big_list))
# this line to remove the duplicates in the list of lists

print (final_list)
```

Considering the sequence matters, that is, [1,1,1,2,3] and [2,3,1,1,1] are two different lists.

What would be the smarter and more comprehensive way to do so?

Comment: Are you looking for `itertools.combinations`?

Comment: @The_spider, thanks for the comment. I am not sure. Does it consider, for example [3, 3, 1, 2, 3] and [3, 3, 1, 3, 2] as two different lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could could use [`itertools.combinations_with_replacement`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement), [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) along with [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> from itertools import combinations_with_replacement, permutations
>>> 
>>> def is_valid_combination(comb: tuple) -> bool:
...     digit_counts = Counter(comb)
...     return digit_counts[1] >= 1 and \
...            digit_counts[2] >= 1 and \
...            digit_counts[3] >= 1
... 
>>> choices = [1, 2, 3]
>>> valid_combinations = [
...     c for c in combinations_with_replacement(choices, r=5)
...     if is_valid_combination(c)
... ]
>>> 
>>> valid_combinations
[(1, 1, 1, 2, 3), (1, 1, 2, 2, 3), (1, 1, 2, 3, 3), (1, 2, 2, 2, 3), (1, 2, 2, 3, 3), (1, 2, 3, 3, 3)]
>>>
>>> all_permutations_of_valid_combinations = {
...     p
...     for c in valid_combinations for p in permutations(c)
... }
>>>
>>> all_permutations_of_valid_combinations
{(2, 1, 3, 1, 2), (2, 1, 3, 2, 1), (3, 3, 2, 1, 3), (1, 2, 3, 2, 3), (1, 2, 1, 3, 1), (3, 1, 2, 3, 2), (3, 3, 3, 2, 1), (3, 2, 2, 1, 1), (1, 2, 2, 3, 1), (1, 3, 2, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2, 3, 2), (1, 2, 1, 1, 3), (3, 1, 3, 3, 2), (3, 1, 1, 2, 3), (2, 1, 3, 2, 3), (1, 2, 2, 1, 3), (1, 2, 1, 3, 3), (2, 3, 3, 1, 2), (2, 3, 3, 2, 1), (3, 3, 1, 2, 1), (3, 2, 3, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2, 3, 3), (3, 2, 1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 1, 3, 1), (2, 3, 1, 1, 1), (1, 3, 1, 2, 3), (3, 3, 1, 1, 2), (3, 2, 3, 1, 2), (2, 1, 2, 3, 1), (2, 2, 1, 1, 3), (3, 2, 1, 3, 1), (2, 3, 1, 3, 1), (1, 1, 3, 2, 1), (2, 3, 2, 1, 2), (2, 3, 2, 2, 1), (2, 1, 2, 1, 3), (3, 2, 1, 1, 3), (2, 2, 1, 3, 3), (2, 3, 1, 1, 3), (2, 3, 1, 2, 2), (3, 2, 3, 3, 1), (1, 1, 3, 1, 2), (2, 1, 2, 3, 3), (3, 3, 2, 2, 1), (3, 1, 2, 1, 2), (3, 2, 1, 3, 3), (3, 1, 2, 2, 1), (2, 3, 1, 3, 3), (1, 1, 3, 2, 3), (3, 3, 3, 1, 2), (1, 2, 3, 1, 1), (1, 1, 3, 3, 2), (3, 1, 3, 1, 2), (2, 3, 2, 3, 1), (1, 3, 2, 1, 1), (2, 1, 3, 3, 1), (3, 2, 2, 3, 1), (3, 1, 2, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2, 2, 2), (1, 2, 3, 1, 3), (1, 3, 2, 3, 1), (3, 2, 2, 1, 3), (2, 2, 3, 2, 1), (3, 1, 1, 2, 2), (1, 1, 2, 2, 3), (2, 1, 3, 2, 2), (1, 3, 3, 2, 2), (3, 3, 1, 3, 2), (2, 1, 1, 3, 1), (1, 3, 2, 1, 3), (2, 1, 3, 3, 3), (3, 1, 3, 2, 2), (2, 2, 3, 1, 2), (1, 1, 2, 3, 1), (3, 2, 1, 2, 2), (1, 2, 2, 3, 2), (3, 3, 1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2, 3, 3), (1, 2, 1, 2, 3), (3, 2, 3, 1, 1), (1, 3, 1, 2, 2), (1, 2, 2, 2, 3), (2, 1, 1, 3, 3), (3, 1, 1, 3, 2), (1, 1, 2, 3, 3), (1, 3, 3, 3, 2), (2, 3, 2, 1, 1), (2, 2, 1, 2, 3), (2, 2, 1, 3, 2), (1, 2, 3, 3, 1), (3, 2, 3, 1, 3), (2, 3, 1, 2, 1), (2, 1, 3, 1, 1), (3, 3, 2, 1, 2), (1, 2, 3, 2, 2), (1, 3, 1, 3, 2), (3, 1, 2, 3, 1), (2, 2, 2, 3, 1), (2, 1, 2, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3, 3, 3), (2, 3, 1, 2, 3), (2, 1, 3, 1, 3), (3, 2, 2, 2, 1), (1, 2, 1, 3, 2), (2, 3, 3, 1, 1), (3, 1, 2, 3, 3), (3, 2, 2, 1, 2), (3, 1, 1, 2, 1), (1, 3, 3, 2, 1), (2, 3, 3, 3, 1), (2, 1, 1, 1, 3), (1, 3, 2, 1, 2), (2, 1, 3, 3, 2), (1, 1, 1, 2, 3), (3, 1, 3, 2, 1), (1, 1, 1, 3, 2), (2, 2, 3, 1, 1), (3, 1, 1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 2, 1, 3), (1, 3, 3, 1, 2), (3, 2, 1, 2, 1), (2, 3, 3, 1, 3), (3, 3, 1, 2, 2), (2, 2, 3, 3, 1), (1, 3, 1, 2, 1), (1, 3, 3, 2, 3), (3, 2, 1, 1, 2), (2, 1, 1, 3, 2), (2, 3, 1, 1, 2), (3, 1, 3, 2, 3), (2, 2, 3, 1, 3), (1, 3, 1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 2, 3, 2), (2, 1, 2, 3, 2), (3, 2, 1, 2, 3), (3, 1, 2, 1, 1), (3, 2, 1, 3, 2), (2, 1, 1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 1, 3, 2), (1, 1, 3, 2, 2), (2, 3, 2, 1, 3), (3, 3, 2, 3, 1), (3, 3, 2, 1, 1), (1, 2, 3, 2, 1), (3, 1, 2, 1, 3), (2, 2, 2, 1, 3), (3, 1, 2, 2, 2), (1, 3, 2, 2, 1), (1, 2, 3, 1, 2), (1, 2, 3, 3, 2)}
```

Comment: thanks! Both yours and mine output 150 results. I assume they are the same! :)

Comment: One thing to note is `all_permutations_of_valid_combinations` is a set if you need a list you will need to cast it into one in an additional step. You may not need to so I did not add into the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the `itertools.combinations` itself, you could use some recursive logic:

```
def combinations(choices, n = 5):
    if n == 1:
        return [[x,] for x in choices]
    else:
        return [v + [x,] for v in combinations(choices, n = n -1) for x in choices]
```

To select only the combinations which contain at least one 1, 2 and 3:

```
[x for x in combinations(choices, n = 5) if all(c in x for c in choices)]
```

Comment: thanks! I've tried it. It outputs some like [3, 3, 3, 3, 3], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]...